# Pillow not importing in VSCode on mac with python 3.10.5 interpreter

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, interpreter

I installed pillow correctly. But when I try to import Pillow in VScode it says module not found. But if I change the interpreter from 3.10.5 to 3.9.13 the error disappears.

The following is how I imported PIL

`from PIL import Image`

Why is this happening? Can someone help please? Thanks

Comment: Are you working with a virtual environment? It may be that it is pointing to another environment or you may also have to restart vscode.

Comment: No, I'm using an M1 mac. I've also restarted both VScode and my M1. Still no change.

Comment: Btw, I have install python using Pyenv. Is that what you meant by virtual environment?

Comment: Yes, I mean that, in the bottom menu bar (at least in windows) it allows you to select the virtual environment of Pyenv. That must be missing.